Curves on a surface corresponding to solutions over function field
In the paper An abcd theorem over function fields and its applications by Corvaja and Zannier the following points were made:

... a curve on the surface $S$ corresponds to a morphism $C \rightarrow S$ from an abstract smooth curve $C$.
This, in turn, corresponds to a solution in $k(C)$ to the equation of the surface $S$.

Here $k(C)$ refers to the function field of $C$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.
For the first point, I suppose both the 'curve' and $C$ are the same thing? I feel that this is analogous to the idea that a $k$-point on a curve $C$ induces a morphism $\mathrm{Spec} k \rightarrow C$.
For the second point, how is the correspondence established? That is, how does a morphism $C \rightarrow S$ induce a solution in the equation of $S$ over $k(C)$?

Sorry for not giving just a comment, but my current status on Math Stackexchange doesn‘t allow to write comments.
To the first point: Curve and C here mean the same object. The difficulty is, that the authors are looking in this article as well on S and C as defined over function fields as on S and C defined over number fields. In the first situation you could look on S as being a „Curve over k(C)“.
To the second Point: in the affine Situation the morphism from C to S induces a homomorphism of the function Field k(S) of S to the function Field k(C) of C, which vanishes exactly on those elements of k(S), which make up the defining equations of S over k(C).
